# jQuery Mobile - 'jquerymobile' shows after link is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I am building a simple web app with jQuery Mobile

Whenever I click a link on an iPhone, I get the little scroller that shows jQuery is requesting the new page.

I then for about half a second got a simple line of text in the top right hand corner saying simply "jquerymobile"

The next page then loads correctly.

Why do I get this line of text with a white background?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doh - somehow had a stray 'jquerymobile' text line in between my JS includes - fixed!